# Delete everything that isn't between brackets

Tags: text-formatting, bioinformatics

I want to delete everything that isn't inside brackets, including the brackets, only in lines that start with ">". Is there a sed alternative? Also, would like to sort lines in alphabetical order by pairs, a.k.a. the line starting with ">" and its next line.

Input example:

```
>ID:000:FLKLNFIA_00192 |[Ignicoccus_hospitalis_KIN4-I.gbfspecies]|strain|Ignicoccus_hospitalis_KIN4-I.gbf|LSU ribosomal protei..|447|FLKLNFIA_1(1297538):162644-163090:1 ^^ Archaeagenomesparanahui Ignicoccus_hospitalis_KIN4-I.gbfspecies strain strain.|neighbours:ID:000:FLKLNFIA_00191(1),ID:000:FLKLNFIA_00193(1)|neighbour_genes:LSU ribosomal protei..,SSU ribosomal protei..| 
ATGAGTGTGACTA---TTT---GCAATCAGCTAGCTACTACGTACTGATCGTAGCTGACG
>ID:000:MGCDKLCO_01184 |[Archaeoglobus_fulgidus_DSM_4304.gbfspecies]|strain|Archaeoglobus_fulgidus_DSM_4304.gbf|50S ribosomal protei..|471|MGCDKLCO_1(2178400):1005279-1005749:1 ^^ Archaeagenomesparanahui Archaeoglobus_fulgidus_DSM_4304.gbfspecies strain strain.|neighbours:ID:000:MGCDKLCO_01183(1),ID:000:MGCDKLCO_01185(1)|neighbour_genes:LSU ribosomal protei..,SSU ribosomal protei..|
ATGCGCGCGATAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTTTAGGGGGATTAGCTA----ACTCTGATTCGGA
```

Expected output:

```
>Archaeoglobus_fulgidus_DSM_4304.gbfspecies
ATGCGCGCGATAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTTTAGGGGGATTAGCTA----ACTCTGATTCGGA
>Ignicoccus_hospitalis_KIN4-I.gbfspecies
ATGAGTGTGACTA---TTT---GCAATCAGCTAGCTACTACGTACTGATCGTAGCTGACG
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'push @l, ">" . join("", /\[(.*?)\]/g) . "\n" . <>;
          END{print for sort @l}' your-file
```

With `sed`:

```
<your-file sed 's/^[^[]*\[/>/
                s/\][^[]*\[\{0,1\}//g
                N;s/\n/\[/' |
  sort |
  tr '[' '\n'
```

Comment: ended up using the perl solution. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My (convoluted) proposal:

```
cat file | grep -Po "^[CGTA-]*$|^>.*$" | grep -Po "(?<=\[).*(?=])|^[ACGT-]*$" | awk '{printf (NR%2==0) ? $0 "\n" : ">"$0"::"}' | sort | sed 's/#/\n/'
```

---

Grep only lines that contains the characters `CGTA-`  and the lines that start with `>`

```
grep -Po "^[CGTA-]*$|^>.*$"
```

---

Grep only what is inside brackets, excluding them, and lines that match the pattern `ACGT-`

```
| grep -Po "(?<=\[).*(?=])|^[ACGT-]*$"
```

---

Join every two lines, adding a separator `#` and the initial `>`, then sort

```
| awk '{printf (NR%2==0) ? $0 "\n" : ">"$0"#"}' | sort
```

---

Finally substitue the separator `#` by a new line

```
| sed 's/#/\n/'
```

---

Output:

```
>Archaeoglobus_fulgidus_DSM_4304.gbfspecies
ATGCGCGCGATAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTTTAGGGGGATTAGCTA----ACTCTGATTCGGA
>Ignicoccus_hospitalis_KIN4-I.gbfspecies
ATGAGTGTGACTA---TTT---GCAATCAGCTAGCTACTACGTACTGATCGTAGCTGACG
```

Comment: nice separator trick. thanks!